# How can I set Camera.Parameters?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am currently learning to develop a camera application. So far, I have managed to use the front and back camera and capture photos. However, I am still confused about the Camera Parameters. I am unsure about where to place the Camera Parameters code. Where and how to set camera parameters?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_camera.htm is a good tutorial regarding with camera parameters. There is a complete project on github which work arround the camera parameters
https://github.com/josnidhin/Android-Camera-Example/blob/master/src/com/example/cam/Preview.java.
You can also find the complete guide of camera on the android developer's page below, 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

Comment: Question with some code doesn't mean that it has good quality. I think you should take a tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

    // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
    Camera.Size previewSize = // .... select one of previewSizes here
    paramters.SetFocusMode(focusvalue);//string focusvalue based on your need
    parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
```

For Camera Parameter Methods you can Refer this link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html